# Solving Word Puzzle?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that finds all words of a certain length or greater that contain required letter x and the remaining letters in the word are drawn from the letters in y (this is a puzzle found in the NYT).

Since I am trying to do this step-by-step, I first create a wordlist of all words of length >= the required length, and then create a list of all words that contain the required letter.

Then I go through each letter in each of the words of that list to see if they contain a letter not in the inputted letters, or use that letter more times than in the inputs. If that happens, I remove the word from the list.

At the end, I print all of the words that satisfy the condition. However, it's not working and I'm not sure why. I'm sure I'm making a really rookie error here but would love any suggestions. Thanks very much, and please forgive my horrific code, I've only been learning Python for two weeks!

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open("wordsEn.txt", 'r')]
req = str(input("Please enter the required letter "))
set = str(input("Please enter the other letters "))
completeset = req + set
lenreq = int(input("Please enter minimum word length "))
panswers = []
usedict = [word for word in data if len(word) >= lenreq]
for word in usedict:
    if req in word:
        panswers = panswers + [word]
panswerstest = panswers
for word in panswerstest:
    for w in word:
        if word.count(w) > completeset.count(w):
            try:
                panswers.remove(word)
            except:
                continue
print(panswers)
```

Comment: Could you explain what output you get when you run the code?

Comment: Also are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Try `panswerstest = panswers[:]` instead of `panswerstest = panswers`.

Comment: The above suggestion from @poke will make a copy of the list, whereas your original code doesn't. That means `panswerstest` and `panswers`refer to the same thing, which can have problems when you're looping over a list as you edit it.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.x, and thanks so much for your initial suggestions, going to work more on this later today. Such a huge world with so much to learn.

Comment: What do you expect the `for` loop after `panswerstest = panswers` to do?

Comment: I was expecting the for loop to go through each word, and then for each word to go through each letter, check to see if the count of that letter in the word exceeded the count of that letter in my set, and if it did, to remove the word from the set of answers.

Comment: poke - thanks so much! Seems to work, now just to find a way to make this more elegant so that it doesn't take forever to run through the dictionary a million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're apparently new to Python, here are a few tips on your code (this is more Code Review than Stack Overflow, but oh well):

- Don’t load the entire word list as a list in the first line; this is very memory-expensive and will slow your program down. A common construction is

  ```py
  with open('myfile.txt') as f:
      for line in f:
          do_stuff_with(line)
  ```

  The `for line in f` loop only loads one line at a time, so there’s never more than a single line in memory at once. That’s much more efficient.

  More generally, you’re creating several large lists: `data`, `panswers` and `panswerstest`. When I tried your code, it choked because the lists were so large. (I started it running when I began writing this answer; it hadn’t finished.)

  It would be better if you checked, a word at a time, whether it matched, printed that to stdout, and then went straight on to the next line.
- Don’t use `set` for a variable name. `set` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html), and overriding those is bad practice (because you will cause things to break in unexpected ways).
- Separate the code for filtering the word list, and the code for getting user input. I’d have at least two functions: `get_user_input()` and `check_word_match(word)`. This makes your code reusable, and you can disentangle the code for wrangling user input (e.g. casting the length to an integer) from the code for matching a word.
- Use longer variable names. Characters are cheap, and it makes it easier to read your code. (e.g. `lenreq` ~> `required_length`, `panswers ~> possible_answers`)
- It's not clear whether matching is case-sensitive (and if it is, you should make it clear to the user). Sprinkling `lower()` throughout your code will help make it case-insensitive, if necessary.
- In Python 3, `input()` returns a string, so there's no need to recast it with `str()`.
- Using a bare `except:` is always a bad idea, because you can catch errors you don’t mean to (this catches *all* errors). It’s better to catch the specific exception you know will be raised.

  In this case, I’m guessing you were throwing a ValueError because you tried to remove an item that wasn’t in the list, so you should use `except ValueError:`. (Although I’m not sure how; once `panswerstest` is a copy of `panswers`, I'm not sure how that could ever occur.)

So here’s how I’d rewrite your code:

```
def get_user_input():
    user_input = {}
    user_input['required'] = input('Please enter the required letter ')
    user_input['additional'] = input('Please enter the other letters ')
    user_input['minimum_length'] = int(input('Please enter the minimum word length '))
    return user_input


def match_word(word, required, additional, minimum_length):
    '''
    Returns True if a word matches the following criteria:
     1) It is at least minimum_length
     1) It contains the required characters
     2) It only contains letters from (required + additional)
    '''
    if len(word) < minimum_length:
        return False

    if required not in word:
        return False

    complete_char_set = required + additional
    for char in word:
        if word.count(char) > complete_char_set.count(char):
            return False

    return True


user_input = get_user_input()

# /usr/share/dict/words is a list of English words found on many Unix
# systems; swap it out for any text file containing a list of words.
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        if match_word(word,
                      required=user_input['required'],
                      additional=user_input['additional'],
                      minimum_length=user_input['minimum_length']):
            print(word)
```

I've separated the code into two functions and cut out all of the large lists. That version runs significantly faster (a few seconds) because there aren’t any large loops to worry about.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an extremely helpful set of suggestions that I am going to study and learn from.

Comment: @redondo87 Glad it was useful! If you want more suggestions like this for future (working) code, the folks on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) are often helpful. :-)